# Node js and certificates reload

Tags: node.js, express, certificate

I run a node js + express https server without problem.
After an event I need to reload the server certificates.
I found these two undocumented functions.

```
global.options.server._sharedCreds.context.setCert(fs.readFileSync('cert/server.crt'));
global.options.server._sharedCreds.context.setKey(fs.readFileSync('cert/server.key'));
```

The swap of certificates works well if after the calling of these two functions I close my browser.
When I re-open the browser and reconnect to my server, the new certificates are present.

Instead I don't understand what happen if I continue with my current browser.
It seems that the new certificates are ignored for a a time.
After that they becomes active.
Is it possible force  node js to reset the connection with client?
Node js version 8.16.

Could someone explain to me what happen after node js load these new certificates?
Thank you in advance.
S.

code to start node js server:

```
global.options = {
    server : https.createServer({
        cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/server.crt'),
        key: fs.readFileSync('cert/server.key'),
        ca: arrCA,
        requestCert: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },app).listen(port, function(){
        const timeEnd = new Date();
        const seconds = (timeEnd.getTime() - timeStart.getTime()) / 1000;
        console.info('\n');
        console.info('################ Node JS is Ready to GO! ################')
        console.info('Time: ' + timeEnd.toLocaleTimeString());
        console.info('Webserver listening on port: ' + port);
        console.info('Webserver loaded in:         ' + seconds + ' seconds!');
        console.info('#########################################################\n')
    })
};
```

#

UPDATE Oct. 4, 2019

Since no one answers, I ask another question for the solution of my problem.
The code above works but I need to close my browser and reopen it to view the new certificate served to client.
So my next question or workaround is:
Is possible close all https opened connections and force a new certificates negotiation?
I tried to force the destroy of sockets but without success.

```
/* example*/
function destroySockets(serverSockets) {
    for (const socket of serverSockets.values()) {
        socket.destroy();
       }
}
```

Do you have any idea how to force browsers to reconnect?
Thanks

Comment: Do you find any solution ?? I think from node >= 11 server.setSecureContext() works better. I am using node 10 and facing this same issue.

Comment: Hi. We have migrated to nodejs 12.

Comment: That is better Sergio , By the way I copied function setSecureContext from https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_tls_wrap.js and it works.

if (typeof httpsServer.setSecureContext === 'function') {
    httpsServer.setSecureContext({ key, cert })
  } else { // Backward compatibility Node < 11
    setSecureContext.bind(httpsServer)({ key, cert })
  }

const setSecureContext = function (options) { ...... }

Comment: You had a good idea.